# Dar click en ventana de chrome con c++

Tags: c++, google-chrome

Actualmente quiero dar click para cerrar una pestaña con este comando, pero me dicen que debo encontar en handle de la ventana, como puedo hacerlo, una sugerencia fue con "FindWindow" pero no se como usarlo...

el código es el siguiente ...

```
SetCursorPos(coordX[2],coordY[2]);

if (SetCursorPos ((int)Coord [x], (int)Coord [y]))
   {
     SendMessage (NULL, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0);
   }

 }
```

Dicen que null es solo para escritorio, y yo quiero hacerlo en google chrome

de antemano gracias

Comment: ¿Qué biblioteca estas utilizando Juank?

Comment: Donde has puesto `NULL` debe ir un handle a la ventana, puedes usar `FindWindow();` para obtenerlo, chrome es código abierto en base a chromium, yo no haría ese desastre que intentas hacer, mi sugerencia sería crear un modulo, cargarlo independientemente y llamar a la función el cual realiza esa tarea...

Comment: Lo intentaré muchas gracias!

Comment: Como dice @nikomaster, lo podrías hacer con una extensión de Chrome. La API que necesitarías usar sería la chrome.tabs: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs